# Mail exception when running a program on a server?

Tags: c#, windows-services, smtp

I have a C# services checker program.  The exe is kicked off from a bat file which also passes in a number of arguments (e.g an int count of how many services you want to check, string of the service display name) and also emailTo, emailFrom, emailServer, etc as if a service is not running a email will be sent.  This is the code for the email part:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(emailFrom, emailTo);
SmtpClient SMTP = new SmtpClient(emailServer);
if (emailUser != "")
{
    SMTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailUser, emailPass);
}
mail.Subject = "The " + service + " service has stopped running";
mail.Body = "Please take a look into the " + 
            service + " service and think about restarting.";

SMTP.Send(mail);
```

So on one server I use emailServer as "localhost" passed in, in the bat file and when it runs if a service that I am checking is not running then the email is sent fine and everything is working.  However on a different server I again use "localhost" as my emailServer but when I run the bat file. I get an error System.Net.Mail.Smtp.Exception [8012], and the email is not sent.  Is this something that is not set up on the server rather than the program that is causing my issue (server config isnt my strong area).

Thanks.

Comment: Use a `try...catch(Exception ex)` around your function and show us `ex.Message` please...

Comment: Does the service account have access to the smtp server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an e-mail server running on the server where your program fails? You are trying to send e-mail to `localhost` (i.e. the computer where your program is executed). If SMTP port 25 is not responding on that machine your e-mail will not be delivered.

For `emailServer` you have to supply the host name of the computer in your network that is able to accept and handle e-mail. Normally you would not use `localhost` for the name of that computer.

Comment: Thanks Martin - just found out there is no email server on the server so the program wont be able to run on this server.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a local e-mail server in order to send e-mail. Assuming that you somewhere in your network have a server that can handle e-mail you should specify that server as the `emailServer`.

Comment: I know that my companies mail server is "mail.mycompany.com" but the problem is this is for an external company - I remote desktop on to their server (Windows 2003 Server) and I tired localhost but it isnt set up - and I dont know what their emailServer is and I am assuming i cant use my comapnies?

Comment: What e-mail server you can use in a LAN depends on how the LAN is configured. Perhaps you have to use a local e-mail server on the LAN, or you need to contact an upstream server at the ISP. You will have to ask the administrators of the LAN. In general you will not be able to use any random e-mail server even it is accessible on the internet because most e-mail servers have restricted access to avoid being used as the source of spam.